# How to define global variables across multiple functions in R? (Not in a package environment)

Tags: r, function, constants

I have a project in R where I am creating a variety of functions and  I have a set of constants that I use in a lot of these functions.

How can I define global variables so they are used across all of my functions? Currently I have to redefine them every time.

Would creating a function for each constant work? Or can I create some kind of constants file and load that in?

Comment: I have this issue to and the answer I am coming to is to create my own package with constants as objects so they can be easily sourced.

Answer (score 1):

That depends. If you're simply using scripts, I believe the best way would be to have a "main" script that calls the others and create a global variable (your "constant"). Something like:

```
global_constant <<- 12345
```

However, if you're developing an R package, consider creating a function that uses the R `options` and defines such behavior when the package is loaded. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817380/how-do-we-set-constant-variables-while-building-r-packages):

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    options(var1='blablabla', var2=12345)

}
```